# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries has the last email N times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

I have an ActionMailer with a method that takes an array, and it sends an email for each item in that array.  I want to check `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` in a test to see if the correct emails were sent.  First, I check the number of emails sent:

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size.should be == my_array.size
```

Yup, the assertion passes as expected.

But `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` seems to have all clones of the last email sent.  Manual testing convinces me that `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` is lying to me -- that unique emails are in fact sent, not the last one N times. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: I have the same problem in Rails 4. I am sending 2 mails in my model and they're different indeed, but in the test I get 2 identical emails in the deliveries array: ```mail(to: @owner.email, subject: t('booking_canceled.action'), template_name: "booking_canceled_to_owner").deliver!

 mail(to: @booker.email, subject: t('booking_canceled.action'), template_name: "booking_canceled_to_booker").deliver!```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this weird behavior too (Rails 3.2.9) and ended up using this ugly workaround:

```
  email = mail(:from => options[:from], :to => options[:to], :subject => options[:subject]) do |format|
    format.text { render :text => options[:text] }
  end
  if Rails.env.test?
    email = Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(email) )
  end
  email.deliver
```

Note that .dup or .clone don't work - .to and .from attributes would be still the same.